# Web part running priority

Tags: sharepoint-2010, web-parts

I have this problem. Currently I developing two web parts. The first(A) generate a query string that the other web part(B) will use. Both are in different pages but in the same site. The problem is:
-When I debug (VisualStudio2010), the web part that needs the query string runs first, and throw me an exception.
So, How can I set priorities to run A first, instead of B??
There is another way ?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me like you either have the web parts on the same page or you have "web part(B)" on your startup page and "web part(A)" on a different page.

Additionally, you should probably be a little more defensive by ensuring your request object has the query parameter before attempting to use it.